# If $f$ is continuous $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ iff $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a continuous function. Prove that the following statements are equivalents:
>
> (i) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$;
>
> (ii) $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**My attempt.**

(i) $\Longrightarrow$ (ii): If $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact, $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed, since $f$ is continuous. If $f^{-1}(K)$ is unbounded, there is a sequence $(x_{n}) \subset f^{-1}(K)$ such that $x_{n} \to \infty$.

I want to conclude that $f(x_{n}) \to \infty$. How can I ensure it?

(ii) $\Longrightarrow$ (i): I dont have a good idea. Can someone help me? I want just a hint, not a solution.

Comment: How do you define $x\to\infty$ exactly? With the one-point compactification?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=e^x$ and the compact set $K=[-1,1]$. Then $\lim f(x)=\infty$ but $f^{-1}(K)=(-\infty,0]$. So either this problem isn't correct or I am losing my mind.

Comment: @SmileyCraft, my book has not yet exactly defined $x \to \infty$. When we work with infinite limits, we use the standard definition.

Comment: @ItsJustLogicBro $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty } e^x =0$. So this isn’t a counterexample.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I see what you are saying now. Let me think if I can patch that.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, I was really confused about this. I had thought that it should be $\Vert x \Vert \to \infty$, but in the question is write just $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa I suspect that someone is simply abusing notation, and we really do want $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @ItsJustLogicBro It is not abusing notation. It is a standard notation for vector maps.

Comment: Since you function is continuous, the inverse image of closed is closed. Hence, condition (i) _signifies_ that the inverse image of bounded is bounded, that is to say, it _signifies_ (ii). Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete  your argument for $(i)$ $\|x_n\|\rightarrow \infty$ implies that $f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$ by hypothesis.

ii)   implies i)Suppose that there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $lim_n\|x_n\|=\infty$ and $f(x_n)$ is bounded, $f(x_n)$ is contained in a closed ball $B$ which is compact, so $f^{-1}(B)=C$ is compact, and bounded by hypothesis, but $x_n\in C$ contradiction since $x_n$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (ii) $\Longrightarrow$ (i)

Take $p \in \mathbb N$. You want to find $M>0$ such that for $\Vert x \Vert >M$ you have $\Vert f(x) \Vert >p$.

The closed ball $K_p$centered on zero with radius $p$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$. $f^{-1}(\mathbb R^n \setminus K_p) = f^{-1}(\mathbb R^n)\setminus f^{-1}(K_p)$. And $f^{-1}(K_p)$ is by hypothesis a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$, therefore bounded and included in a closed ball centered on zero with a radius $M>0$.

Where are done: the image of a point $x$ with a norm $>M$ is such that $\Vert f(x)\Vert >p$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $x_n\to\infty$ I am used to is that for every compact set $K$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $x_n\not\in K$. So then the statement $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$ would literally mean that for every compact set $K$ there exists compact set $L$ such that for all $x\not\in L$ we have $f(x)\not\in K$, so $f^{-1}(K)\subseteq L$.

I would like to mention how this elegant definition can be made precise with topology. In topology we say that $x_n\to x$ if for every open set $U$ containing $x$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $x_n\in U$. There is also a thing in topology called the one-point compactification of a topological space $X$. The idea is to add a "point at infinity", so you get $X\cup\{\infty\}$, and the open sets containing $\infty$ are exactly the complements of the compact sets in $X$.

Comment: Its a very clever proof for bounded! I didnt know this definition, is that a topological property?